# centering a div or input element vertically using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OHp2.png

My code rn:

```
<body class="bg-light">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input class="form-control" list='datalistOptions' placeholder="Where would you like to travel?">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: You can use my-auto class to make content vertically center respective to it's container

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items-center` and `min-vh-100` with your row

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
<body class="bg-light">
        <div class="row container-fluid justify-content-center position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input class="form-control" list='datalistOptions' placeholder="Where would you like to travel?">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `align-items-center` and `min-vh-100` to your `row`. Like this:

```
<body class="bg-light">
 <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center min-vh-100 mt-3">
  <div class="col-6">
   <input class="form-control" list='datalistOptions' placeholder="Where would you like to travel?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Search</button>
  </div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve this. But let's take a look at how it is done in CSS and compare it to the utility classes in Bootstrap.

Considering we have the following HTML

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

---

Solution with CSS Flex

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;

  /* Center Horizontally */
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Center Vertically */
  align-items: center;
}
```

Solution with Bootstrap Flex Utilities

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

---

Solution with CSS Grid

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  
  /* Center both vertically and horizontally */
  place-items: center;
}
```

Solution with Bootstrap Grid Utilities.
Unfortunately, there is no class for `place-items-center`. Therefore, you can use inline styles

```html
<div class="d-grid" style="place-items:center">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Bear in mind that for you to be able to center anything in the middle of the screen, you'll have to define a height to the parent. If you are using any block level element such as `div` the width is already `100%`. But the height will always follow the content. In the screenshot you shared, it seems like you want to center it in the middle of the screen. For that you'll have to add `vh-100` (View Height 100) to the parent to have it expand to the full height of the screen.